# add xml attribute value based on other attribute from same tag using bash and xmlstarlet

Tags: bash, xslt, attributes, xmlstarlet

I have following xml structure
input.xml

```
<route order="1" xml:base="directory/filename1.xml">
    <name>name1</name>
</route> 
<route order="2" xml:base="directory/filename2.xml">
    <name>name2</name>
</route>
```

I want as output.xml

```
<route order="1" xml:base="directory/filename1.xml" xml:timestamp="2017-08-30_12:00:00">
    <name>name1</name>
</route> 
<route order="2" xml:base="directory/filename2.xml" xml:timestamp="2017-05-30_12:30:00">
    <name>name2</name>
</route>
```

where xml:timestamp is the result of the date function with the xml:base as input

```
date -r directory/filename1.xml +'%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S'
```

I can add a xml:timestamp attribute like this

```
xmlstarlet ed --insert "/route" --type attr -n xml:timestamp -v 2017-08-31 input.xml
```

but how do I pass the result of the date function to the -v ?

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the result returned from the date command by placing the complete command in $() and so the follwoing should work:

```
xmlstarlet ed --insert "/route" --type attr -n xml:timestamp -v "$(date -r directory/filename1.xml +'%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S')" input.xml
```

Comment: thanks for the quick respons. But how do I use the xml:base attribute value in the $() as parameter ?

Comment: You could use $(sed -En 's@^.*order=\"1\" xml:base=\"(.*)\" xml:timestamp.*$@\1@p' filename). Change the order number accordingly.

Comment: Thanks Raman for the respons. This works, but what if I had several hundred tags with attribute order="..." ? Is it possible to transform the file with a xslt ?

Comment: You can read all the entries into an array with readarray arr <<< "$(sed -En 's@^.*xml:base=\"(.*)\">$@\1@p' xml)"